# Specify test method name prefix for test suite in junit 3

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, junit3

Is it possible to tell JUnit 3 to use additional method name prefix when looking up test method names?

The goal is to have additional tests running locally that should not be run on continuous integration server. CI server doesn't use test suites, it look up for all classes which name ends with "Test" and execute all methods that begins with "test".

The goal is to be able to locally run not only tests run by integration server, but also tests which method name starts with, for example "nocitest" or something like that.

I don't mind having to organize tests into tests suite locally, since CI is just ignoring them.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to specify this, it's hard coded in JUnit.

Your best option is to split the two sets of tests into two sets of classes, called (say) XxxTest and XxxUnit or something like that. Then in your CI server, you can specify just the *Test classes.